# "Sorry, there's been a disconnect. We can't find the page you're looking for."

Tags: powerapps, portal

I got access to one of the company  URL, which works for all my collegues. ( https://make.powerapps.com/environments/GUID)

but get the below error "Sorry, there's been a disconnect. We can't find the page you're looking for. Please verify the link and try again."
I do have the Community Environment with the same work account and this is the work environment that I just got access but I have the error. Wondering why I cannot connect to this environment, and if interference between the 2. Sorry, pretty green on this.
Appreciate your input,

Answer (score 0):

Could be you don't have environment maker rights in that environment.